The SwiftUI line chart is not displaying the values at each data point
In SwiftUI, I'm having trouble with a line chart where the value annotations for each data point are not displaying as expected. Specifically, the annotations for each LineMark are not showing up on the chart, even though I have tried several different approaches and modifications to fix the issue. I've adjusted various settings, including the annotation position and chart configuration, but the problem persists. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me troubleshoot this and figure out what might be causing the annotations to not appear properly. Any guidance or suggestions would be highly appreciated!
enter image description here


import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Charts



struct TemperatureData: Identifiable ,Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var day: String
    var detailDay: String // detail time
    var temperature: Double = 0.0
}


struct LineChartViewData : Identifiable ,Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var startY: Double
    var endY: Double
    var dataArray:  [TemperatureData]  = []

    func getWeeklyData()-> [[TemperatureData]] {
        var twoDimensionalArray: [[TemperatureData]] = []
        var subarray: [TemperatureData] = []
        for element in self.dataArray {
            subarray.append(element)
            if subarray.count == 7 {
                twoDimensionalArray.append(subarray)
                subarray = []
            }
        }
        if(!subarray.isEmpty) {
            twoDimensionalArray.append(subarray)
        }
        return twoDimensionalArray
    }
  
}

struct LineChartView: View {
    var lineChartViewData: LineChartViewData
    @State private var selectedWeek: Int = 0
   
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
  
         
        
         
            TabView(selection: $selectedWeek) {
                ForEach(0..<lineChartViewData.getWeeklyData().count, id: \.self) { weekIndex in
                    VStack{
                        Chart (lineChartViewData.getWeeklyData()[weekIndex]) { item in
                            
                            LineMark(
                                x: .value("Time", item.day),
                                y: .value("Temperature", item.temperature)
                            )
                             
                            .symbol(Circle())
                            .interpolationMethod(.catmullRom)
                            .annotation(position: .top) {
                                Text("\(item.temperature, specifier: "%.1f")")
                                    .font(.caption)
                            }
                            
                        }
                        .chartYScale(domain: lineChartViewData.startY...lineChartViewData.endY)
                        .chartYAxis {
                            AxisMarks(position: .leading)
                        }
                    }.tag(weekIndex)
                }
            }.frame(height: 150).tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
                .onAppear {
                   
                    selectedWeek = lineChartViewData.getWeeklyData().count - 1
                }
      
        }
    
    }
}

struct LineChartView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let temperatureData: [TemperatureData] = [
            TemperatureData(day: "9-9", detailDay: "9-9",temperature: 36.5),
            TemperatureData(day: "9-10", detailDay: "9-9",temperature: 36.3),
            TemperatureData(day: "9-11", detailDay: "9-9",temperature: 36.4),
            TemperatureData(day: "9-12",detailDay: "9-9", temperature: 36.2),
        ]
        
        LineChartView(lineChartViewData:LineChartViewData( startY: 35, endY: 43,dataArray: temperatureData))
    }
}



